# Eclipse emptied my Manifest and Project Descriptor files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, manifest

So I'm working on this project and I used Microsofts OneDrive to save my workspace, so I can easily access it from everywhere.
So today I started Eclipse and updated the ADT through the SDK Manager. Then an error showed up that told me to update the SDK too and so I did. The error kept showing up, but eclipse worked.

Now I tried to open my project and it told me that the project descriptor file is unusable.
Opening my project folder I see the ".project" and the "AndroidManifest.xml" files completely empty!

I have to finish this project by wednesday and I don't know what to do!
Any help appreciated.

inb4 y u no backup

Comment: for safety purpose always keep the backup of your code, but for now i thinks you can rewrite the manifest.xml easily.

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar what about the .project file?

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar I don't want to sound rude, but you're not helping much. I have no idea what to write in it since I'm a very unexperienced developer. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @Wischm0pp,Just copy/paste the AndroidManifest.xml file from another application and make the corrective change in it, like change the package name,activity name and add the other things that your application required. And what type of help you expect by me, tell me, if possible i will do.